# Postgres wal archivation delay

Tags: postgresql, backup, archive, wal

I've noticed a lag of archive_command execution. The command is configured to set a flag on arhived segment:

```
archive_command = 'rm pg_xlog/*.backuped ; touch %p.backuped'
```

If I run `ls` then I see that a lot of segments are not archived:

```
000000010000098800000029
00000001000009880000002A
00000001000009880000002B
00000001000009880000002C
00000001000009880000002D
00000001000009880000002E
00000001000009880000002F
000000010000098800000030
000000010000098800000031
000000010000098800000032
000000010000098800000032.backuped
000000010000098800000033
000000010000098800000034
000000010000098800000035
000000010000098800000036
000000010000098800000037
000000010000098800000038
000000010000098800000039
00000001000009880000003A
00000001000009880000003B
00000001000009880000003C
00000001000009880000003D
00000001000009880000003E
00000001000009880000003F
000000010000098800000040
000000010000098800000041
000000010000098800000042
000000010000098800000043
```

Is this correct behaviour? How do I save those last segments to not lose them on server crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer segments are probably old segments that have been "recycled" in preparation for future use, but not yet used (and so not needed for recovery)